# StackExchange.Redis.TimeoutException

Tags: .net, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I have an Azure function set up to receive MS Graph webhook notifications, and a few times a day it gets relatively heavy load (1K req/sec for a few seconds). I'm using a distributed Redis lock to limit the actual handling of those events, but often receive timeouts. I've read the recommended guidance and I'm not seeing an obvious issue from the error message. I've made sure to use a singleton connection and I increased the thread pool count to 200. What am I missing?

> Timeout awaiting response (outbound=0KiB, inbound=0KiB, 5156ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms), command=HMGET, next: HMGET CacheKeyRedacted, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: SpinningDown, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 5316, last-in: 1, cur-in: 0, sync-ops: 0, async-ops: 10796, serverEndpoint: redacted.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, conn-sec: 132342.43, aoc: 0, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: redacted(SE.Redis-v2.7.4.20928), IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=200,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=3,Free=1020,Min=200,Max=1023), POOL: (Threads=27,QueuedItems=4,CompletedItems=2499702,Timers=134), v: 2.7.4.20928 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

Comment: "What is causing the timeout?" (From comment on an answer below) - ultimately, either a: "we didn't get a timely response from the server", or b: "we stalled in the library" - "a" is incredibly hard to pin down, and could be "the server stalled", "the network stalled", "some hidden proxy stalled" (many cloud redis providers use a proxy/relay between you and redis), or anything else! Have you looked at "slowlog" to see if there's anything obvious going on at the server?

Comment: @Marc Gravell I've looked a few times and it never has any data. "slowlog get" always returns "(empty array)"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following settings to your connection string:

```
connectRetry=8,connectTimeout=15000,syncTimeout=15000
```

Comment: I feel like increasing the timeout is just putting a band-aid on it. What is causing the timeout?